# How to migrate QSizePolicy form Pyside6 to PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt6

code below works fine with PySide6 but what is equivalent for PyQt6?

```
sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

When I run it using PyQt6 I get the error:
AttributeError: type object 'QSizePolicy' has no attribute 'Preferred'

I tried substituting:

```
 sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.setHorizontalPolicy(Preferred), QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

Also doesnt work

Comment: Since Qt6 all enum require their full namespace. `QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred` etc. Note that `QSizePolicy.setHorizontalPolicy(Preferred)` is wrong and nonsensical: 1. `setHorizontalPolicy()` acts on a size policy instance, but you're trying to call it on the class; 2. it returns `None`, so it's invalid for a QSizePolicy constructor; 3. `Preferred` alone won't work since `Preferred` is presumably not defined (and if it is, it probably is for something else, which will give unexpected results or throw an exception).